# Return Object Name With The Biggest Points Property In a List Of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, max

I have `players` containing multiple objects within. My end goal is to return the `name` property of the object with the highest `points` value.

For example this block should return a string of  *Bob*

```
const players = [

   { 
      name: 'Jack',
      points: 3
   }

   { 
      name: 'Jill',
      points: 2
   }

   { 
      name: 'Bob',
      points: 4
   }

]


for(i = 0; i < players.length; i++){

   // return string of name property of object with highest value in points

}
```

I'm not sure how to execute this inside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reduce` it

```
players.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
   return (acc.points || 0)<obj.points ? obj : acc;
},{})
```